# android:cellid and lac not working

Tags: android, telephony

I am making an app in which i have to get the lac and cell id . I am using

```
private PhoneStateIntentReceiver mPhoneStateReceiver;
ServiceState state = mPhoneStateReceiver.getServiceState();

 int cid = state.getCid();
 int lac = state.getLac();
```

and its giving error that PhoneStateIntentReceiver cannnot resolved to type and getcellid and getlac is also giving errorthat getcellid is undefined for ServiceState

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to get cid and Lac

```
 final TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (telephony.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
    final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony.getCellLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        msg.setText("LAC: " + location.getLac() + " CID: " + location.getCid());
    }
}
```

with permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Sujit,When i used lacc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lacc);
 lacc.setText(location.getLac()); // exception    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Comment: use  lacc.setText(" "+location.getLac()); because  location.getLac() returns int not string.

Comment: Thanks for help and +1 for it.

Comment: Surjit, have you any idea how to get roaming on device means whether the device is in roaming or not?